# Blazor webassembly: How to inject controller from `foo.Sever` to `foo.Client`?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Development environment: I am using .NET 5 official release, Visual Studio 2019 preview (latest). As you known, creating new project by Visual Studio 2019 use Blazor webassembly project. When we named project `foo`, Visual Studio scaffolding 3 projects

- `foo.Shared`
- `foo.Client` (has dependency with `foo.Shared`)
- `foo.Server` (has dependency with `foo.Shared`)

In Blazor server-side, I did like this

[image]

I put controller inside `foo.Sever` ,  As you know, `foo.Client` did not use dependency `foo.Server` . How to call controller from `foo.Client` by injecting?

I need some extend ideal for this reality problem (guide me best practice call controller from `foo.Client` (Razor pages)).

Comment: You can not inject a service that is designed for the server into a client on a browser.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1,  when it is a simple service that can run on WebAssembly:

  - Place it in the Shared Project or in a similar Class library that is and can be referenced by both the Server and Client projects.
- Option 2,  when the service needs server based resources (like a database)

  - Create an API endpoint on the server and call it from the Client

You will usually want option 2.

Comment: Side note: Controller is not a convenient name when you already have API controller(s)